# pay when calling in sick

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

My wife has recently called in sick and the boss has said to her that she must pay £70 for each day she doesn't come in. Is that right??

This isn't a reduction as she is hourly paid but just asking her outright for £70.  She's a hairdresser in a busy salon.

Comment: This depends on the laws of your country. There's no global law for sick day pay. It might even be dependent on her specific work contract.

Comment: If she's a UK employee then absolutely definitely not. But I know some hairdressers are self employed, which changes things a lot.

Comment: sorry...in UK..

Comment: And in the UK hairdressing is an job where that are some non standard employment customs and practice

http://www.hji.co.uk/hair/hairdresser-chair-rental-and-t/

Comment: I think you need to get some more details on this.  Hairdresser's usually rent the space (chair, supplies, etc) they are using.  They aren't typically "employees"  in the normal sense so it might be perfectly within the owner's rights to let your wife know that she still needs to pay her "rent".

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how I know this, but here goes...

As @Dan's comment says, she may be self employed.  A salon works a bit like a market stall.  The stall-holder (the hairdresser) rents a pitch (the space in the hairdresser in this case).  This is charged by day whether you use it or not (as they could rent it to someone else).  In your case the rental is £70 a day (covering the salon's costs and profit), after this, any money taken should be your wife's.  I'm not sure about hourly pay, any hairdresser/barbers I've seen carefully note each type of job they do (cut/perm/colour etc) and this tallys towards their pay (so doing 5 colour and perm is better than 10 dry cuts for example)

What you should be doing, is finding a sub-let for any day you can't work, who will at least cover the £70 fee (and they keep any additional taking on that day, or maybe some kind of fee to you for use of the pitch), you may need to get them pre-screened by the salon, who'll want to ensure they keep their clientèle happy with the required experience/quality.

Comment: She can also contact her clients scheduled for those days she will miss and arrange someboy else to do their hair to makeup for the stall rental costs, some sort of profit sharing with the gal/guy that will see those clients